# when I Using Three20 to Launch another UITabBarController in a TTLauncherView ,Original UITabBarController Tabbar Can't disappear

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, three20, ttlauncherview

when I launch another UITabBarController in a LaunchView, the TTLauncherView is in the page in the original UITabBarController, the Dest Controller is another UITabBarController, but the Original UITabBarController's TabBar can't disappear.

So, in the UI, I have two TabBars, the Original TabBar in the Bottom, the second Dest Controller View display in the screen except the bottom tabbar.

This is not what I want.  How to solve this problem to hide the Original TabBar and let the second Dest Controller to display Full Screen?

In the first Controller, I launch second controller by LauncherView button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the tab bar view when pushing the new controller using

```
controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Take a look on this tutorial from three20 wiki, it explains on how to hide the tab bar when pushing another controller.

http://three20.info/article/2010-11-10-Hiding-The-iphone-Tab-Bar-With-TTNavigator